# How many TCP sessions can port 80 handle?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, port

As far as everyone knows, port 80 is reserved for HTTP servers. Suppose there is a server running a Web service, how many simultaneous TCP sessions this port can accept in the same time? Does it depend on the server OS?

Comment: Are you asking *how* or *how many*? NB Port 80  is reserved for HTTP, not HTML. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> port 80 is a reserved port for HTML service

There is no HTML service. You probably mean HTTP.

> how many simultaneous TCP sessions this port can accept in the same time?

This depends on application settings, OS, OS settings and resources available on the system.